# sqlplus: command not found on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, sqlplus

I just installed Oracle Database 11g R2 on Ubuntu.

I tried to run `sqlplus` but I got this message :

```
sqlplus: command not found
```

These are the values of : $ORACLE_SID, $ORACLE_HOME and $PATH

```
aimad@localhost:/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_2/bin$ echo $ORACLE_SID

aimad@localhost:/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_2/bin$ echo $ORACLE_HOME
/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_2/
aimad@localhost:/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_2/bin$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/sbin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/bin/X11:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin:/root/bin
```

How can I solve this problem ?

Answer (score 2):

Add path `/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_2/bin` (because sqlplus is here) to `$PATH` variable:

```
PATH=$PATH:/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_2/bin
export PATH
```